# How to sync multiple Palm PDA devices?

Tags: synchronization

I am using a Palm Tungsten E2 PDA which I sync to a linux machine via jpilot. jpilot is kind of ugly but it works and it is sufficient to look up things on the computer.

Now I want to sync the same data to a 'backup' Palm PDA (m150). First tests with jpilot did not work as expected, because it seems that the devices differ too much and jpilot is too dependent on different database file formats (i.e. I guess the devices internally use different database schemas).

Syncing to the backup PDA m150 works with j-pilot, when a fresh `~/.jpilot` config is used.

How can I solve this? Is there is some GUI which supports to sync to multiple devices (and abstracts away device differences)?

Since I am using Ubuntu 10.04 I assume that KDE Akonadi is not a solution because it is too alpha.

Comment: Using Palm's Windows sync software (palm desktop) I've transferred data and apps between many generations of PalmOS PDA - so it is possible in principle.

Comment: Maybe this will work: Create another fresh `~/.jpilot` directory. Start J-Pilot. Go to `File > Preferences`. Make sure that Datebook, Address, and Memo are all set to use the old-style database formats. Sync J-Pilot with the Tungsten E2. Again make sure that Datebook, Address, and Memo are all set to use the old-style database formats. Now sync J-Pilot with the m150. Does this copy over the data as expected?